# The complement of an asymmetric relation is nonsymmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

**Asymmetric relation**: Given a set A and a relation R in A, R is asymmetric if it is never the case that for any ordered pair (x, y) in R, the pair (y, x) is in R.

**Nonsymmetric relation**: If for some (x, y) in R, the pair (y, x) is not in R then R is nonsymmetric.

**Complement**: The complement of a relation R contains all ordered pairs of the Cartesian product of A which are not members of R.

The book that I am reading says that the complement of an asymmetric relation is nonsymmetric.

Isn't this a counterexample: The set A is empty and relation R has no ordered pairs (i.e., R is empty).

R is asymmetric.

The complement of R is R, which is not nonsymmetric.

So, is the book incorrect?

Comment: Does your textbook **allow** relations on the empty set?

Comment: Hmm, good question. It doesn't seem to explicitly prohibit relations on the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $(x,y) \in R$; then by [asymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation): $(y,x) \in R^C$.

Obviously $(x,y) \notin R^C$.

Thus, we have found a pair $(a,b) \in R^C$ such that the pair $(b,a) \notin R^C$, that means that $R^C$ is [not symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation).